# C# Printing with Font Styles

Tags: c#, printing

I want to print some text like this.

> This is **how** i want to **print** the text.

the code i am using is

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stringToPrint = "This is how i want to print the text";
        printFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 10);
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
        try
        {
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;

        ev.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, printFont,
            ev.MarginBounds.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
            out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, printFont, Brushes.Black,
            ev.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        ev.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);

    }
```

I want to change the Font from regular to bold or give an Underline for some specific words in the string.

And if there is another Better way to do this job then please tell me i'll change my code.
Please Help me Out! :)

Comment: did you have any success by creating several fontstyles in the same file before you printed?

Comment: no, if i had done that then it would not have been a problem!

Comment: are you getting an error, or is the problem that it just prints all in the same font?

Comment: maybe a silly question, but as you have a form already, why not add a hidden RichTextControl, add the formatted text then print the contents of the RichTextControl?

Comment: #Philip. RichtextControl did it. Another way is HTML using webBrowser. Thanks.

Answer (score -5):

You can try:

```
  printFont  = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Bold);
```

ThangNguyen

Comment: This will bold all the words in his string, which is not what he wants. His problem is not easy at all.