# write a string to a text file with a specific font and size

Tags: c#

I want to write a string to a text file with a specific font and size.

For example, write a string "Start Order", with Tahoma font and size 10. 
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
my code

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:/filename.csv");
StringBuilder builder = "the, text, to, print";
sw.WriteLine(builder);
```

but I have no idea where to specify font and size(Tahoma 10)

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this yourself?  What have you tried?  If you want help, you need to ask for specific help with something you are having trouble with.  This is too general of a question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308324/c-sharp-printing-with-font-styles

Comment: Text files cannot have the font type nor the font size specified. However, some file types can, such as a pdf file or an rtf file. Unless you are creating one of these files, then you cannot. If you are creating one of these type of files, then you should change your question to specify what file format you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

To a **text file**? If you mean that literally, then the answer is: you can't.

By definition, a **text file** is simply a file containing text, no formatting information. There is no way to specify e.g. a font face or size.

Programs that can open the text file can themselves usually be configured to display and/or print the text with user-selected formatting. But that's not a question about the text file itself; it's a question about the tool you're using to look at the text file.

If you think the above doesn't answer your question, then please provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates what you mean by "text file", what you've tried already in terms of setting formatting in that "text file", and why what you've tried so far doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said, this cannot be done in the .csv file. You can however, you can use the first 2 pieces of data (font and font size) as the font to use in your program.
For example:

```
string font = "Tamoha";
float size = 10;

this.lbl.Font = new Font(font, size);
```

This will set the new font style to anything you want as long as you correctly read in `font` and `size` from the .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

the text in file just like 'data', the text format just like 'view', some program (notepad, etc) open the text file and use a default text format on the text.